# Get-Help for .trim / -trim, .replace / -replace, .split / -split and other string operators

Tags: string, powershell, console, operators, help-system

PowerShell has a pretty good built-in help system that I use a lot and I'm able to see all help options with `Get-Help *` and query Cmdlets or can look up Topics with `Get-Help about_*` and then say `Get-Help about_compar*` to open the **Comparison Operators** topic which is all very good.

However, I was trying to find how to get help on the various string operators, like .replace, .compare, .split, .substring. Does anyone know how to pull these topics up on the PowerShell console (possibly, they might be hidden inside some of the about_* topics, but it's not obvious or clear to me where to look)?

Also, the string operators have -replace, -compare, -split variants etc and while almost the same as the .replace etc, one version uses regular expressions and the other does not. Does anyone know if there are help topics (again, available from the console!) that clarifies all of this? The PowerShell help system will feel quite lacking if it is missing clarifications on all of this in its built-in help system as these are a very heavily used part of the language (so hopefully this is all tucked away in some about_* topics that I've not found yet).

Comment: The `.Replace()`, `.Split()` methods are in the .NET `System.String` class. They aren't ***PowerShell*** commands. Therefore, they don't have typical `Get-Help` pages. I know this does not give you the answer you are looking for, but the easiest thing to do is just go to [System.String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8) and expand Methods.

Comment: What I normally do is i.e. `$i='mystring'` and then `$i.Split`. That gives me all the different variations of `Split`. Or I check the MS Documentation online i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8#methods . In Powershell I only found this command `get-help about_methods -full` but it does not help me much..

Comment: Thanks Dan, as you say, $i.split (and $i | Get-Member) give me a lot and then I can just iterate through the Methods. That's good for .replace(), .split(), as just seeing the OverloadDefinitions on the console is pretty useful. Any ideas on getting info on the -replace(), -split() forms on the console also? Ah, I also see things like "System.StringSplitOptions options" and that's not very informative in terms of what the valid split options might be.

Comment: Good point AdminOfThings, I didn't realise that. Is there any more we can do on the console to pull info from the `System.String` class do you think?

Comment: When I do `$i.Split` as per your suggestion Dan, we see:
`string[] Split(string[] separator, System.StringSplitOptions options)` as one of the definitions. Is there a command-line that might give us just a bit more info about the valid possible values for `StringSplitOptions options` do you think? That would help a lot.

Comment: @roysubs  `[Enum]::GetNames([StringSplitOptions])` will help.

Comment: The `[Enum]::GetNames` is extremely useful, so now I can examine a great deal about these methods from the console, thanks.

Comment: Does anyone know any more about the `-replace / -split` methods (which use regex)? They have different characteristics from `.replace() / .spli()` (which split on each characters presented) - so presumably they are *not* a part of `System.String`. Are they in fact part of PowerShell and if so, is this an area that Microsoft have not documented in their `about_*` or other helpfiles?

Comment: I've found some of them ... `about_Split` has information on the PowerShell operator `-Split` and `about_Comparion_Operators` and `about_Regular_Expressions` contains information on the `-Replace` and `-Match` PowerShell operators. I don't know if this covers all of the operators, but looks like they might all be covered in the documentation available on the console so that's good.

Comment: I was trying to output the `System.String` information from a function and I don't know why it's not working. if I do `"".split` *on the console*, then I get the details of the `System.String` returned. However, if I take that and put it into a function `function test($cmd) { if ($cmd -eq 'split') { echo "".split ; break } }` and then run the function, the "".split part returns *nothing* (when I woulc like to just return the info from `System.String` that I get when I run `"".split`. Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As has been noted, ***methods* of .NET types** such as `System.String.Split()` are not part of *PowerShell*, but of the .NET framework that PowerShell is built on, so you'll have to **consult the official documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com**.
- That said, given the close integration between PowerShell and .NET, it would be nice to be able to easily consult this documentation from within PowerShell - see [GitHub issue #11338](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11338).
- However, ***operators* such as `-split` *are* PowerShell language features, and both discovering their documentation altogether and getting focused, operator-specific information is currently cumbersome**.

  - Documentation for language features such as operators is contained in `about_*` help topics, which can be targeted with `Get-Help -Category HelpFile`, and you can combine that with passing the (quoted) name of the operator in order to search the *contents* of these topics:

    - For example, **`Get-Help -Category HelpFile -Name '-replace'` at least narrows the search down**, but still includes all help topics that *mention* `-replace`; the result will comprise the **[about_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators) help topic, which is the overview page** that links to more specific pages focused on specific *categories* of operators, such as arithmetic operators, comparison operators, ..., but also describes some general-purpose operators *directly*.
- There is currently no direct way to get focused information for a given operator, but there should be: see [GitHub issue #11339](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11339).

---

Below are two **helper functions that try to overcome the current limitations (as of v7.3.0), `Show-OperatorHelp` and `Show-TypeHelp`**.

Note:

- Both functions (of necessity) don't show the documentation *in the console* (terminal), but open the online documentation in your default *web browser*.

  - In `Show-TypeHelp`, support is limited to those (public) types that ship with .NET and therefore have documentation pages at https://learn.microsoft.com.
  - `Show-OperatorHelp` opens the specific section describing just the operator of interest whenever possible; some operators, such as the arithmetic operators `+`, `-`, don't have individual sections, but the overall topic is usually short enough in these cases to make it easy to find the parts of interest.
- They come with comment-based help, so you can use `-?` and `Get-Help` to learn more about them.
- You can place them in your `$PROFILE` file, for instance, or - given their length - you may want to create *external scripts* (*.ps1) based on them that you place in a directory listed in `$env:Path`. To that end, simply strip the `function <name> {` line and the final `}` and save them to a `*.ps1` file.

#### Example uses:

**`Show-OperatorHelp`**:

```
# Opens the home (overview) page for all PowerShell operators
Show-OperatorHelp

# Lists all operators in the console, 
# along with their friendly names and categories.
Show-OperatorHelp -List

# Opens the help topic (section) for the -replace operator.
# Equivalent of 
    Show-OperatorHelp -Name '-replace'
# because you omit the initial '-'; if you do specify it, quote the entire argument.
Show-OperatorHelp replace

# Opens the help topic (section) for @(...), the array-subexpression operator.
# Note the need for quoting.
Show-OperatorHelp '@()'
```

**`Show-TypeHelp`**:

```
# Opens the documentation for the System.String.Split() method.
#  You can specify a type name ('string' in this example) as follows:
#    * Use a full type name, with the initial 'System.' component optionally omitted (e.g. 'Text.Encoding' for 'System.Text.Encoding'
#    * Use a type accelerator such as 'xml' for 'System.Xml.XmlDocument'
# Tab-completion: You can type (part of) a the name of a type
# (last component of the full name) and cycle through loaded types by that name.
# E.g., typing `arrayli` tab-completes to 'System.Collections.ArrayList'.
# Alternatively, *pipe* an instance of a string to the function (see next example).
Show-TypeHelp string split # Short for: Show-TypeHelp -Type string -Member split

# Opens the documentation for the [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]
# type, instances of which Select-String outputs.
'foo' | Select-String o | Show-TypeHelp
```

**I suggest getting the source code from the following MIT-licensed Gists instead**, as only they will be maintained; assuming you have looked at the code (which I can personally assure you is safe, but you should always check), you can **install them directly**:

```
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/146f3202a810a74cb54a2d353ee4003f/raw/Show-OperatorHelp.ps1 | iex

irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/50a1b101cd53978cd147b4b138fe6ef4/raw/Show-TypeHelp.ps1 | iex
```

---

Note: Ignore the broken syntax highlighting below.

#### `Show-OperatorHelp` source code:

```
function Show-OperatorHelp {
  <#
.SYNOPSIS
Shows documentation for PowerShell's operators.

.DESCRIPTION
Navigates to operator-specific or -related online help topics in your default 
web browser.

Invoke argument-less to see the operators overview help topic.
-Precedence shows the topic about operator precedence.
-QuotingRules shows the topic about string literals and quoting.
-Name <name> targets a specific operator.

.PARAMETER Name
The name of an operator.

Note that most names must be passed *in quotes* for syntactic reasons;
e.g., '-match' instead of -match
However, you may omit the initial '-', in which case you needn't quote.

Use -List to see all names.

.PARAMETER Precedence
Opens the help topic that describes operator precedence.

.PARAMETER List
Parameter description

.PARAMETER QuotingRules
Opens the help topic that describes the quoting rules and syntax for
string literals.

.PARAMETER CopyUrl
Instead of opening the topic page in a browser, copies the page's URL to
the clipboard.

.PARAMETER Version
Specify a specific PowerShell version number (e.g., 7 or 5.1) for which to
display the requested help topic.
By default, the executing engine's version number is used.

.EXAMPLE
Show-OperatorHelp

Opens the home (overview) page for all PowerShell operators.

.EXAMPLE
Show-OperatorHelp replace

Opens the help topic (section) for the -replace operator.
Equivalent of: Show-OperatorHelp -Name '-replace'

.EXAMPLE
Show-OperatorHelp -List

Lists all operators, along with their friendly names and categories.

.EXAMPLE
Show-OperatorHelp -Precedence

Shows the help topic about operator precedence.
#>

  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'HomePage', SupportsShouldProcess, PositionalBinding = $false)]
  param (
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Name', Mandatory, Position = 0)]
    [string] $Name
    ,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Precedence')]
    [switch] $Precedence
    ,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'List')]
    [Alias('ListAvailable')]
    [switch] $List
    ,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'QuotingRules')]
    [Alias('StringLiterals')]
    [switch] $QuotingRules
    ,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Name')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Precedence')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'QuotingRules')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'HomePage')]
    [Alias('cp')]
    [switch] $CopyUrl
    ,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Name')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Precedence')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'QuotingRules')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'HomePage')]
    [string] $Version # PowerShell version
  )

  # Default to the executing PowerShell engine's version.
  # Note: If no "?view=powershell-<ver>" query string is present,
  #       the currently highest stable version overall is targeted.
  if ($Version) {
    $verObj = $Version -as [version]
    if (-not $verObj) { $verObj = "$Version.0" -as [version] }
    if (-not $verObj) { Throw "Unrecognized PowerShell version number: $Version" }
  }
  else {
    $verObj = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
  }
  $Version = ('{0}.{1}' -f $verObj.Major, $verObj.Minor) -replace '\.0$'

  $opTable = @{
    # about_Arithmetic_Operators
    '-'            = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-'; FriendlyName = 'subtraction / sign inversion'; Topic = 'about_Arithmetic_Operators'; Category = 'Arithmetic' } 
    '*'            = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '*'; FriendlyName = 'multiplication / string replication'; Topic = 'about_Arithmetic_Operators'; Category = 'Arithmetic' } 
    '/'            = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '/'; FriendlyName = 'division'; Topic = 'about_Arithmetic_Operators'; Category = 'Arithmetic' } 
    '%'            = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '%'; FriendlyName = 'modulus'; Topic = 'about_Arithmetic_Operators'; Category = 'Arithmetic' } 
    '+'            = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '+'; FriendlyName = 'addition / string conatenation'; Topic = 'about_Arithmetic_Operators'; Category = 'Arithmetic' } 
    '-band'        = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-band'; FriendlyName = 'bitwise AND'; Topic = 'about_Arithmetic_Operators'; Category = 'Bitwise' } 
    '-bor'         = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-bor'; FriendlyName = 'bitwise OR'; Topic = 'about_Arithmetic_Operators'; Category = 'Bitwise' } 
    '-bxor'        = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-bxor'; FriendlyName = 'bitwise XOR'; Topic = 'about_Arithmetic_Operators'; Category = 'Bitwise' } 
    '-bNot'        = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-bNot'; FriendlyName = 'bitwise complement'; Topic = 'about_Arithmetic_Operators'; Category = 'Bitwise' } 
    # about_Assignment_Operators
    '='            = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '='; FriendlyName = 'assignment'; Topic = 'about_Assignment_Operators'; Category = 'Assignment' } 
    '+='           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '+='; FriendlyName = 'compound assignment'; Topic = 'about_Assignment_Operators'; Category = 'Assignment' } 
    '-='           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-='; FriendlyName = 'compound assignment'; Topic = 'about_Assignment_Operators'; Category = 'Assignment' } 
    '*='           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '*='; FriendlyName = 'compound assignment'; Topic = 'about_Assignment_Operators'; Category = 'Assignment' } 
    '/='           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '/='; FriendlyName = 'compound assignment'; Topic = 'about_Assignment_Operators'; Category = 'Assignment' } 
    '%='           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '%='; FriendlyName = 'compound assignment'; Topic = 'about_Assignment_Operators'; Category = 'Assignment' } 
    '++'           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '++'; FriendlyName = 'increment'; Topic = 'about_Assignment_Operators'; Category = 'Assignment' } 
    '--'           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '--'; FriendlyName = 'decrement'; Topic = 'about_Assignment_Operators'; Category = 'Assignment' } 
    # about_Comparison_Operators
    '-eq'          = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-eq'; FriendlyName = 'equality'; Topic = 'about_Comparison_Operators'; Anchor = '-eq'; Category = 'Equality' } 
    '-ne'          = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-ne'; FriendlyName = 'inequality'; Topic = 'about_Comparison_Operators'; Anchor = '-ne'; Category = 'Equality' } 
    '-gt'          = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-gt'; FriendlyName = 'greater-than'; Topic = 'about_Comparison_Operators'; Anchor = '-gt'; Category = 'Equality' } 
    '-ge'          = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-ge'; FriendlyName = 'greater-than-or-equal'; Topic = 'about_Comparison_Operators'; Anchor = '-gt'; Category = 'Equality' } 
    '-lt'          = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-lt'; FriendlyName = 'less-than'; Topic = 'about_Comparison_Operators'; Anchor = '-lt'; Category = 'Equality' } 
    '-le'          = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-le'; FriendlyName = 'less-than-or-equal'; Topic = 'about_Comparison_Operators'; Anchor = '-le'; Category = 'Equality' } 
    '-like'        = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-like'; FriendlyName = 'wildcard matching'; Topic = 'about_Comparison_Operators'; Anchor = '-like'; Category = 'Matching' } 
    '-notlike'     = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-notlike'; FriendlyName = 'negated wildcard matching'; Topic = 'about_Comparison_Operators'; Anchor = '-notlike'; Category = 'Matching' } 
    '-match'       = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-match'; FriendlyName = 'regular-expression matching'; Topic = 'about_Comparison_Operators'; Anchor = '-match'; Category = 'Matching' } 
    '-notmatch'    = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-notmatch'; FriendlyName = 'negated regular-expression matching'; Topic = 'about_Comparison_Operators'; Anchor = '-notmatch'; Category = 'Matching' } 
    '-replace'     = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-replace'; FriendlyName = 'regular-expression-based string replacement'; Topic = 'about_Comparison_Operators'; Anchor = 'replacement-operator'; Category = 'String' } 
    '-in'          = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-in'; FriendlyName = 'LHS contained in RHS'; Topic = 'about_Comparison_Operators'; Anchor = '-in'; Category = 'Containment' } 
    '-notIn'       = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-notIn'; FriendlyName = 'LHS not contained in collection'; Topic = 'about_Comparison_Operators'; Anchor = '-notin'; Category = 'Containment' } 
    '-contains'    = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-contains'; FriendlyName = 'collection contains RHS'; Topic = 'about_Comparison_Operators'; Anchor = '-contains'; Category = 'Containment' } 
    '-notContains' = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-notContains'; FriendlyName = 'collection doesn''t contain RHS'; Topic = 'about_Comparison_Operators'; Anchor = '-notcontains'; Category = 'Containment' } 
    # about_Join
    '-join'        = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-join'; FriendlyName = 'string joining'; Topic = 'about_Join'; Category = 'String' } 
    # about_Split
    '-split'       = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-split'; FriendlyName = 'string splitting'; Topic = 'about_Split'; Category = 'String' } 
    # about_Logical_Operators
    '-not'         = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-not'; FriendlyName = 'logical NOT'; Topic = 'about_Logical_Operators'; Category = 'Logical' } 
    '!'            = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '!'; FriendlyName = 'logical NOT'; Topic = 'about_Logical_Operators'; Category = 'Logical' } 
    '-and'         = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-and'; FriendlyName = 'logical AND'; Topic = 'about_Logical_Operators'; Category = 'Logical' } 
    '-or'          = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-or'; FriendlyName = 'logical OR'; Topic = 'about_Logical_Operators'; Category = 'Logical' } 
    '-xor'         = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-xor'; FriendlyName = 'logical XOR'; Topic = 'about_Logical_Operators'; Category = 'Logical' } 
    # about_Operators
    '$()'          = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '$()'; FriendlyName = 'subexpression'; Topic = 'about_Operators'; Anchor = 'subexpression-operator--'; Category = 'Evaluation' } 
    '@()'          = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '@()'; FriendlyName = 'array-subexpression'; Topic = 'about_Operators'; Anchor = 'array-subexpression-operator--'; Category = 'Evaluation' } 
    '()'           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '()'; FriendlyName = 'grouping'; Topic = 'about_Operators'; Anchor = 'grouping-operator--'; Category = 'Evaluation' } 
    '. '           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '.'; FriendlyName = '(dot-)source'; Topic = 'about_Operators'; Anchor = 'dot-sourcing-operator-'; Category = 'Execution' }   # Sadly, we have to use '. ' to distinguish it from the member-access operator
    '&'            = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '&'; FriendlyName = 'call (execute)'; Topic = 'about_Operators'; Anchor = 'call-operator-'; Category = 'Execution' }
    ' &'           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '&'; FriendlyName = 'background'; Topic = 'about_Operators'; Anchor = 'background-operator-'; Category = 'Execution' } # Sadly, we have to use ' &' to distinguish it from the call operator
    '&&'           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '&&'; FriendlyName = 'pipeline-chain AND'; Topic = 'about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators'; Category = 'Pipeline' }
    '||'           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '||'; FriendlyName = 'pipeline-chain OR'; Topic = 'about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators'; Category = 'Pipeline' }
    '|'            = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '|'; FriendlyName = 'pipeline'; Topic = 'about_Operators'; Anchor = 'pipeline-operator-'; Category = 'Pipeline' }
    '.'            = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '.'; FriendlyName = 'member access'; Topic = 'about_Operators'; Anchor = 'member-access-operator-'; Category = 'Object' } 
    '::'           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '::'; FriendlyName = 'static member access'; Topic = 'about_Operators'; Anchor = 'static-member-operator-'; Category = 'Object' } 
    '[0]'          = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '[0]'; FriendlyName = 'index'; Topic = 'about_Operators'; Anchor = 'index-operator--'; Category = 'Object' } 
    '[int]'        = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '[int]'; FriendlyName = 'cast / type constraint'; Topic = 'about_Operators'; Anchor = 'cast-operator--'; Category = 'Type' } 
    ','            = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = ','; FriendlyName = 'array constructor'; Topic = 'about_Operators'; Anchor = 'comma-operator-'; Category = 'Array' } 
    '..'           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '..'; FriendlyName = 'range (numbers/characters) '; Topic = 'about_Operators'; Anchor = 'range-operator-'; Category = 'Array' } 
    '-f'           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-f'; FriendlyName = 'format (strings)'; Topic = 'about_Operators'; Anchor = 'format-operator--f'; Category = 'String' } 
    '?:'           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '?:'; FriendlyName = 'ternary conditional'; Topic = 'about_Operators'; Anchor = 'ternary-operator--if-true--if-false'; Category = 'Conditional' } 
    '??'           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '??'; FriendlyName = 'null-coalescing'; Topic = 'about_Operators'; Anchor = ''; Category = 'Conditional' } # ?? Not yet covered in the v7 topic as of 12 Dec 2019
    # about_Redirection
    '>'            = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '>'; FriendlyName = 'redirection'; Topic = 'about_Redirection'; Category = 'Stream' }
    '>>'           = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '>>'; FriendlyName = 'appending redirection'; Topic = 'about_Redirection'; Category = 'Stream' }
    # about_Type_Operators
    '-is'          = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-is'; FriendlyName = 'type(-inheritance) / interface test'; Topic = 'about_Type_Operators'; Category = 'Type' } 
    '-isnot'       = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-isnot'; FriendlyName = 'negated type(-inheritance) / interface test'; Topic = 'about_Type_Operators'; Category = 'Type' } 
    '-as'          = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '-as'; FriendlyName = 'conditional type conversion'; Topic = 'about_Type_Operators'; Category = 'Type' } 
    # --- Not covered by an operator help topic, but could be considered one.
    # about_Splatting
    '@'            = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = '@'; FriendlyName = 'splatting (arguments)'; Topic = 'about_Splatting'; Category = 'Splatting' } 
  }

  # As a courtesy, interpret variations of quotes / quoting styles passed as -Name as if -Quoting had been passed instead.
  $parameterSetNameInEffect = $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
  if ($Name -replace '\s' -match '^(?:''''?|""?|@''(''@)?|@"("@)?)$') {
    $parameterSetNameInEffect = 'QuotingRules'  
  }

  $url = ''

  switch ($parameterSetNameInEffect) {

    'Name' {

      $warning = ''

      # See if the name matches an entry as-is.
      $entry = $opTable[$Name]

      # If '.' was passed, warn about member-access / dot-sourcing ambiguity.
      if ($Name -eq '.') {
        $warning = "Defaulting to member-access operator; for the dot-sourcing operator, pass '. '"
      }
      elseif ($Name -eq '&') {
        $warning = "Defaulting to call operator; for the background operator, pass ' &'"
      }
      elseif ($Name.Trim() -eq '@') {
        $warning = "Defaulting to splatting operator; for the array-subexpression operator, pass '@()'; for here-strings, pass '@`"`"@' or -QuotingRules"
      }
      elseif (-not $entry) {
        # Remove any spaces, to support name variations such as '( )', '[ ]'
        $normalizedName = $Name -replace ' '
      }

      if (-not $entry) {
        # If not, try prepending "-", to allow users to specify 'replace' instead of '-replace', for instance.
        $entry = $opTable["-$normalizedName"]
      }
      if (-not $entry) {
        # Variations of redirection operators.
        if ($entry -match '^[\d*]?>>?(&\d?)') {
          $entry = $opTable['>']
        }
      }
      if (-not $entry) {
        # Map case variants to their unqualified form; e.g. '-ireplace' -> '-replace'
        $baseName = $normalizedName -replace '^(?=-?)[ci](?=[a-z])'
        if ($baseName -ne $normalizedName) {
          if ($baseName -notlike '-*') { $baseName = '-' + $baseName }
          $entry = $opTable[$baseName]
        }
      }
      if (-not $entry -and $normalizedName -like '`[*`]') {
        # varations of referring to the index / cast / type-constraint operator
        $bracketName = $normalizedName
        if ($bracketName -eq '[]') {
          $bracketName = '[0]' # default to indexer, but warn
          $warning = "Defaulting to index operator; for the cast / type-constraint operators, pass '[int]'"
        }
        elseif ($bracketName -match '^\[(\d+|[''"].*[''"])\]$') {
          $bracketName = '[0]' # indexer - numeric or string
        }
        else {
          $bracketName = '[int]' # cast
        }
        $entry = $opTable[$bracketName]
      }

      if (-not $entry) {
        Throw "Not a recognized operator: $Name"
      }
      elseif ($warning) {
        Write-Warning $warning
      }

      $url = "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/" + $entry.Topic
      if ($entry.Anchor) {
        $url += '#' + $entry.Anchor
      }
      break
    }

    'Precedence' {
      $url = 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operator_Precedence'
      break
    }

    'QuotingRules' {
      $url = 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules'
      break
    }

    'HomePage' {
      $url = 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators'
      break
    }

    'List' {
      # List the operators table below.
    }

    Default { Throw "What are you doing here?" }
  }

  if ($url -and $Version) {
    $versionQueryString = '?view=powershell-' + $Version
    if ($url.Contains('#')) {
      $url = $url -replace '(#.+)$', ($versionQueryString + '$1')
    }
    else {
      $url += $versionQueryString
    }
  }

  # -WhatIf support.
  if (-not $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess((("`n" + $url + "`n"), "List all operators")[$parameterSetNameInEffect -eq 'List'])) { return }

  if ($parameterSetNameInEffect -eq 'List') {

    $opTable.Values | Select-Object Name, FriendlyName, Category | Sort-Object Category, Name

  }
  else {

    if ($CopyUrl) {
      Write-Verbose "Copying URL to clipboard: $url"
      Set-Clipboard $url
    }
    else {
      Write-Verbose "Navigating to: $url"
      Start-Process $url
    }

  }
}
```

---

#### `Show-TypeHelp` source code:

```
function Show-TypeHelp {
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
  Shows documentation for built-in .NET types.

  .DESCRIPTION
  Navigates to the specified .NET type's learn.microsoft.com documentation page
  in your default web browser, assuming the type comes with .NET.

  Use -WhatIf to preview the URL that would be opened.

  There are two basic invocation patterns:

  * Provide the full name of a type a type accelerator or a [type] instance
    via the -Type parameter.

     * Tab-completion works with the (prefixes of) a type's simple name (without
      namespace component); e.g., Get-TypeHelp List<tab> cycles through all
      loaded types whose name is or starts with 'List'.

  * Pipe instance(s) of the type of interest.

  .PARAMETER Type
  Can be the name of a type (e.g. "string"), or a type literal (e.g. [string]).
  
  If given a name, the name must be one of the following:
   * The type's full name; e.g., 'System.Xml.XmlDocument'.
   * The full name with the 'System.' prefix omitted; e.g., 'Xml.XmlDocument'
   * The name of a PowerShell type accelerator; e.g., 'xml'

  .PARAMETER Member
  The optional name of a property or method to get specific information on.
  If the target type has no such member, a warning is issued, and you're taken
  to the type's home page.

  .PARAMETER InputObject
  Object(s), typically provided via the pipeline, whose type's documentation
  page should be opened.

  .PARAMETER Platform
  The target .NET platform / standard, which must include a specific major.minor
  version number; e.g., 'dotnetcore-3.1'.
  Currently (v7.0), the latest 'netframework-*' version is targeted by default, i.e.,
  the Windows-only .NET Framework (FullCLR).

  Use tab completion to cycle through the available platforms, but note that
  you must complete the specific version number yourself.

  .EXAMPLE
  Get-TypeHelp xml

  Opens the documentation page for type [xml], i.e., for System.Xml.XmlDocument

  .EXAMPLE
  Get-TypeHelp string split

  Opens the documentation page for the System.String type's Split() method.

  .EXAMPLE
  Get-Item / | Get-TypeHelp

  Opens the documentation page for type System.IO.DirectoryInfo, an instance
  of which is output by the Get-Item command.

  .EXAMPLE
  Get-TypeHelp regex -Platform netcore-3.1

  Opens the documenation page for type System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
  for the .NET Core 3.1 platform.
  #>

  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ByType', SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]
  [OutputType()] # No output.
  param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ByType', Mandatory, Position = 0)]
    [ArgumentCompleter( {
        param($cmd, $param, $wordToComplete)
        # Remove enclosing / opening quote(s), if present.
        $wordToComplete = $wordToComplete -replace '^[''"]|[''"]$'
        if ($tp = $wordToComplete -as [Type]) {
          # Already a full type name or the name of a type accelerator such as [xml]
          $tp.FullName
        }
        else {
          # Get the full names of all public types (including nested ones), but exclude dynamic assemblies.
          # (Dynamic assemblies can't be expected to have documentation pages anyway; also, not excluding them would break the .GetExportedTypes() call.)
          $allLoadedTypes = [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where( { -not $_.IsDynamic }).GetExportedTypes().FullName
          # Prefix-name-only-match against all loaded full type names from non-dynamic assemblies at
          # and enclose in embedded '...' if the type name contains a ` char. (generics), then sort.
          $(foreach ($match in $allLoadedTypes -match "[+.]$wordToComplete[^.]*$") {
              ($match, "'$match'")[$match -match '`']
            }) | Sort-Object
        }
      })]
    [Type] $Type
    ,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ByType', Position = 1)]
    [string] $Member
    ,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ByInstance', ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    $InputObject
    ,
    [ArgumentCompleter( {
        'netcore-', 'netframework-', 'xamarinmac-', 'dotnet-plat-ext-', 'netstandard-', 'dotnet-uwp-', 'xamarinandroid-', 'xamarinios-10.8', 'xamarinmac-' -like "$wordToComplete*"
      })]
    [string] $Platform
    ,
    [Alias('cp')]
    [switch] $CopyUrl
  )
  
  begin {
    $types = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Type]]::new()
    $instances = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
  
    if ($Platform -and $Platform -notmatch '^[a-z][a-z-]+-\d+\.\d+$') {
      Throw "The -Platform value must be in the form '<platform-id>-<major>.<minor>'; e.g., 'netcore-3.1'; use tab completion to cycle through the supported platforms and add a version number."
    }
  }
  process {
    switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
      'ByType' { $types.Add($Type) }
      'ByInstance' { $instances.Add($InputObject) }
      Default { Throw 'What are you doing here?' }
    }
  }
  end {
  
    # If instances were given, determine their types now.
    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByInstance') {
      $types = $instances.ToArray().ForEach('GetType') | Select-Object -Unique
    }

    $urls = foreach ($tp in $types) {
      # Make sure that the member exists, otherwise a 404 happens.
      if ($Member -and $tp.GetMembers().Name -notcontains $Member) {
        Write-Warning "Ignoring member name '$Member', because type '$tp' has no such member."
        $Member = ''
      }
      # Transform the full type name to the format used in the URLs.
      # '`1' -> '-1'
      # System.Environment+SpecialFolder -> 'System.Environment.SpecialFolder'
      $typeNameForUrl = $tp.FullName -replace '`', '-' -replace '\+', '.'
      "https://learn.microsoft.com/$PSCulture/dotnet/api/$typeNameForUrl" + ('', ".$Member")[$Member -ne ''] + ('', "?view=$Platform")[[bool] $Platform]
    }
  
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("`n" + ($urls -join "`n") + "`n")) { 
      if ($CopyUrl) {
        Write-Verbose "Copying URL(s) to clipboard: $urls"
        Set-Clipboard $urls
      }
      else {
        Write-Verbose "Navigating to: $urls"
        Start-Process $urls
      }
    }
  
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an incredible piece of work that you've done here @mklement0, thanks so much. I was thinking of working on something similar (a lookup on each operator but I was probably never going to get around to it and your version is massively better than what I would be able to develop). Hugely appreciate that you've done all of this for this answer and I can only hope that Microsoft import stuff like this into the core language as ease of use is worth a lot in my opinion and this really helps in getting to the help info. Thanks again, really great scripts here(!) will go into my $profile. :-)

Comment: I'm glad the answer is helpful and I appreciate the nice feedback, @YorSubs. I have actually created two feature requests on GitHub (see the links I've added to the top of the answer), so you can up-vote them there. I suggest you grab the code from the linked Gists instead of from this answers: I've already made changes there and will only maintain the code there going forward (you'll have to wrap the code in `function <name> { ... }`).