# How to get the filename from PowerShell GUI

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I'm making a program to change various icons through RegEdit, and I figured a nice GUI where people can choose which .ico files they would like their file changed to would be a good touch. Only thing is, I know nothing about PowerShell, but it was much easier to manipulate RegEdit than with Python. And I know less so about PowerShell GUI.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{ 
    InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop') 
    Filter = 'Icons (*.ico)|*.ico'
}
$result = $FileBrowser.ShowDialog()
<#What do here?#>
```

The last line, where the comment is, what do I do to get the string, or whatever datatype, that contains the file name I just searched for? For anyone curious, that `$FileBrowser` just gives a default Windows file search window, which I just placed a `.ico` restriction on. What method do I call? I read something about `DialogResult` but I don't understand how that method or applet ties in to `ShowDialog` nor how it is used to obtain the filename, (if that is the right solution)

Answer (score 2):

- `$FileBrowser.ShowDialog()` returns an enumeration value that tells you whether the user confirmed (`OK`) or canceled (`Cancel`) the dialog.

  - See the [`OpenFileDialog` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog), the [`ShowDialog()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.commondialog.showdialog#System_Windows_Forms_CommonDialog_ShowDialog), and the [`System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.commondialog.showdialog#System_Windows_Forms_CommonDialog_ShowDialog) enumeration
- If the user confirmed, `$FileBrowser.FileName` contains the full path of the chosen file.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{ 
    InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop') 
    Filter = 'Icons (*.ico)|*.ico'
}

if ('OK' -eq $FileBrowser.ShowDialog()) {
  "User chose: $($FileBrowser.FileName)"
}
else {
  'User canceled the dialog.'
}
```

<sup>Note: You can use *strings* in PowerShell in lieu of enumeration values, which PowerShell automatically converts; you can also use the enumeration values explicitly, but that is more verbose; e.g., `'OK'` vs. `[System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK`.</sup>

---

As for **discovering the involved types and their member**s:

- You can use the [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) cmdlet on a variable to discover its value's .NET type and that type's members.
- To get more information about a given .NET type, you can simply google google it, or construct and open a URL programmatically as follows:

```
$result = $FileBrowser.ShowDialog()

# Get the full name of the type of the value stored in $result
$fullTypeName = $result.GetType().FullName

# Assuming the type is one that comes with .NET,
# look up its documentation online (using the default browser).
Start-Process "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/$fullTypeName"
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59324892/45375) contains a convenience function named `Show-TypeHelp` that wraps the above.

Answer (score -2):

`$Result | Get-Member`

This will show you the way.