# In powershell why we are using "-gt" and what it means?

Tags: powershell

In this command what is "-gt 1" and "-f".

```
Get-PSDrive | ?{$_.Free -gt 1} | %{$Count = 0; Write-Host "";}{$_.Name + ": Used: " + "{0:N2}" -f ($_.Used/1gb) + “Free: " + "{0:N2}" -f ($_.Free/1gb) + " Total: " + "{0:N2}" -f (($_.Used/1gb)+($_.Free/1gb)); $Count = $Count + $_.Free;} {Write-Host ""; Write-Host "Total Free Space " ("{0:N2}" -f ($Count/1gb)) -BackgroundColor magenta}
```

Comment: I commend to your attention the output of [`Get-Help about_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7).

Comment: Search terms with characters such as `-` are hard to google. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59324892/45375) for a PowerShell function that enables direct lookup of help for PowerShell operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-gt 1` is a [Comparison Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7) meaning "Greater Than" 1

`-f` is a [Format Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#format-operator--f) so that you can format the output string.