# PowerShell $_ syntax

Tags: powershell, syntax, pipe, help-system

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41836207/2125110) the author proposed the following snippet:

```
dir -Path C:\FolderName -Filter *.fileExtension -Recurse | %{$_.FullName}
```

I can understand the majority of it, but I'm unable to search documentation for the last part. The output of the search is piped `|` and used in `%{}` and as `$_`.

I have experimented around it, `%{}` is a for-each statement I believe, [bing search was not effective](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell+%25%7B%7D&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powershell+%25%7B&sc=8-13&sk=&cvid=32AE75E1FEB0406FA98C18F9F741FF1F). `$_` is also somewhat magic: it is a variable, with no name and thus immediately consumed? I don't care much for the `.FullName`, that part I sorted out. Again, [bing search was not effective](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell+%24_&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powershell+%24_&sc=1-13&sk=&cvid=D62C3EA028ED4E1393BEE779E7CB9F9B), nor searching for those char sequences in PowerShell docs.

Can anybody explain it to me?

Comment: It represents the object(s) passed down the pipeline. That's why you were able to reference the property of `.Fullname`.

Comment: Just like you would store an object  in a variable,  such as : `$Var = Get-Process -Name wuasrv` in this case, I can reference the objects properties using dot notation: `$Var.Name`, `$_` is the same concept. It's a place holder for the actual object passed down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `%{}` is not "a thing" - it's two things: `%` and `{}`

`%` is an alias for the [`ForEach-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object):

```
PS ~> Get-Alias '%'
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           % -> ForEach-Object
```

... so it resolves to:

```
... |ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
```

`ForEach-Object` is basically PowerShell's [`map` function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) - it takes input via the pipeline and applies the operation described in the `{}` block to each one of them.

`$_` is an automatic reference to the current pipeline input item being processed

You can think of it a bit like a `foreach($thing in $collection){}` loop:

```
1..10 |ForEach-Object { $_ * 10 }
# produces the same output as
foreach($n in 1..10){
    $n * 10
}
```

Except we can now stick our loop in the middle of a pipeline and have it produce output for immediate consumption:

```
1..10 |ForEach-Object { $_ * 10 } |Do-SomethingElse
```

---

`ForEach-Object` is not the only thing that makes use of the `$_` automatic variable in PowerShell - it's also used for pipeline-binding expressions:

```
mkdir NewDirectory |cd -Path { $_.FullName }
```

... as well as *property expressions*, a type of dynamic property definition supported by a number of cmdlets like `Sort-Object`:

```
1..10 |Sort-Object { -$_ } # sort in descending order without specifying -Descending
```

... `Group-Object`:

```
1..10 |Group-Object { $_ % 3 } # group terms by modulo congruence
```

... and `Select-Object`:

```
1..10 |Select-Object @{Name='TimesTen';Expression={$_ * 10}} # Create synthetic properties based on dynamic value calculation over input
```

Comment: One nice thing about Visual Studio Code is if you install the powershell addin it will warn you about using alias and tell you what the alias refers to.

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Mathias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66567025/45375), which explains the specific constructs well, with **how you could / couldn't have discovered this information yourself, using *PowerShell's own help system***:

**Relevant help topics and use of the help system**:

Note: To get an **overview** of all aspects of PowerShell's help system, simply **run `help`**.

- `%` is a built-in [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases) for the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

  - Use `Get-Help ForEach-Object` to view the help topic in the terminal.

    - If no local topics are found, you must download them via the [`Update-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/update-help) cmdlet.
  - Tips:

    - Add the `-Online` switch to open the (potentially more current) [online version](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) of the topic in your browser.
    - You can bootstrap your use of [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help) with `Get-Help Get-Help` (or even `help help`):

      - Cmdlet-specific help comes in *detail levels*: terse (default, shows the syntax and overview description only), `-Detailed` (includes parameter descriptions and example commands) and `-Full` (additionally includes technical parameter information and extended notes).
      - `-Examples` can be used to show example commands only.
      - With keyword-based search (see below), you can limit results to topics of a certain category with the `-Category` parameter.
    - For convenience, you can also use the built-in `help` *function*, which wraps `Get-Help` calls with display paging (simply put: by piping the output to the `more` utility) and defaults to detail level `-Full`.
- `{...}` is a [*script block* literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), a block of arbitrary PowerShell code that can be invoked on demand:

  - `help about_Script_Blocks` shows the topic locally; the `about_` prefix indicates that the topic is a *conceptual* help topic (rather than one covering a specific command); when you use `Get-Help` to search for a keyword (see below), you can (somewhat obscurely) limit the results to conceptual topics with `-Category HelpFile`.
  - Note: As of this writing, `about_` topics can *not* yet be directly viewed online by adding `-Online` - see [GitHub issue #13550](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13550) - but it's easy to google them by name.
- `$_` is a [variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Variables), as the `$` sigil followed by an identifier implies, and is more specifically an [*automatic* (built-in) variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables):

  - `help about_Variables` covers variables in general.
  - `help about_Automatic_Variables` covers the automatic ones.

---

**How the above can / cannot be discovered based on symbols and aliases alone:**

Doing a web search for symbols is notoriously unhelpful.

- As an aside: Running distinct syntax constructs such as `%` and `{ ... }` together without whitespace between them (e.g. `%{$_.FullName}`) constitutes an additional barrier, and should therefore be avoided.

**Narrowing your search by using only PowerShell's help system helps, but only *to a limited degree***:

- `%`

  - Because `Get-Help` is aware of aliases, **`help %` actually works fine** and directly shows `ForEach-Object`'s help topic.
  - `help % -Examples` shows example commands that include the use of script blocks and the automatic `$_` variable.
- Even though **`Get-Help` supports *keyword-based* search**, **searching for *symbol-based* terms `{}` and `$_` directly *isn't* helpful**, because even when limiting the search to *conceptual* (`about_`-prefixed topics) with `-Category HelpFile`, there are either too many hits (`help '$_' -Category HelpFile`) or the relevant topic doesn't show at all (`help '{}' -Category HelpFile`)
- `$_` can be discovered *indirectly*, IF you already know that it is an instance of a *variable*:

  - `help variables -Category HelpFile` happens to take you directly to the relevant (local) [about_Automatic_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables) topic,
  - whereas `help variable -Category HelpFile` *lists* the following matching topics `about_Variable_Provider`, ``, `about_Automatic_Variables`, `about_Preference_Variables`, `about_Remote_Variables`, `about_Variables`, and `about_Environment_Variables`
  - Note: Thanks to PowerShell's pervasive support for [*wildcard expressions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), you could have performed the search also as follows: **`help about*variable*`** - be sure to enclose *both* sides of the search term in `*`.
- `{...}` can be discovered *indirectly*, IF you already know that it is an instance of a script (code) *block*:

  - **`help about_*block*`** takes you directly to the relevant (local) [`about_Script_Blocks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) topic.

---

**Potential future improvements:**

- It would be a great improvement if PowerShell's help system supported focused *symbol*-based searches.
- Similarly, the ability to directly look up *operators*, such as `-match`, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match), would be helpful:

  - [GitHub issue #11339](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11339) proposes just that.
  - On a related note, [GitHub issue #11338](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11338) proposes adding the ability to look up documentation for *.NET types* (online).
  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59324892/45375) contains custom functions `Show-OperatorHelp` and `Show-TypeHelp`, which fill that gap for now (also available as Gists).

Comment: I'd give +2 on this one. Websearch (especially on MS systems...) could help a little more. I didn't know about the help function, PowerShell is still pretty new to me.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @DaemonPainter. PowerShell is pretty "self-aware" in general - other helpful commands are [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) and [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) - but the help system certainly has room for improvement. Note that PowerShell (Core) 7+ now provides a bootstrapping hint when you enter an interactive shell: `Type 'help' to get help.` Running `help` shows a high-level overview of PowerShell's help system.

Comment: Nice extra documentation. Some concepts are clearer for me now !