# You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Tags: python, docker, powershell, terminal

i get this error when im trying to start the docker-compose with the "" command  docker-compose -f localdevhelpers/docker-compose.yml  -f mediaservice/docker-compose.yml up

```
% : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ % docker-compose -f localdevhelpers/docker-compose.yml  -f mediaservi ...

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:PSObject) [ForEach-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

- Your problem boils down to a **simple confusion between the `&`, the *call operator* and `%` the built-in alias of the *`ForEach-Object` cmdlet***.
- However, the resulting error message is confusing and therefore worth explaining - see below.
- Additionally, guidance on how to discover the meanings of symbols used in PowerShell is provided.

---

Instead of `%`, **use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) to execute a command**, such as the external `docker-compose` program; however, given that you specified the program's name *unquoted* (and given that it doesn't contain special characters that would *require* quoting and that it isn't expressed via a variable reference), you do not even need `&` in this case:

```
# Note: & is optional in this case.
& docker-compose -f localdevhelpers/docker-compose.yml -f mediaservice/docker-compose.yml up
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

**`%` is a built-in alias of the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet**, whose purpose isn't to invoke commands, but to operate on (typically) multiple inputs from the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines).

The **reason for the - obscure - error message** ("cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"):

`ForEach-Object` is often used with one or more [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) to operate on - e.g. `1..3 | ForEach-Object { 1 + $_ }`

However, it also supports [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax), whose *syntax* requirements your call *accidentally* met, which then led to the - obscure - runtime error:

- Syntax form `% foo bar ...` (`ForEach-Object foo bar ...`) causes `foo` to be interpreted as the name of a *.NET method*, with `bar` and any subsequent arguments being considered the arguments to pass *to that method*.
- The specified method is called on *each input object*, but - in the absence of pipeline input - there is *no* input object, so `ForEach-Object` sees *`$null`* in lieu of an actual input object. Because methods cannot be invoked on `$null`, the error message you saw was reported.

---

**Inspecting commands and operators**:

You could have used [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help) or [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) to determine what `%` refers to:

```
# `Get-Help %` or even `% -?` would print help.
PS> Get-Command %

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           % -> ForEach-Object
```

This works, because **`%` is a *command* (an alias)**.

Among commands, it is *unusual* in that it is a *symbol* rather than a *word-based name*; another exception is `?`, which is a built-in alias of the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet (because `?` is a [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) metacharacter, you actually have to use ``` Get-Command ``? ``` or ``` Get-Help ``? ```).

**Other symbols are *not* commands - they're usually *operators***, which you cannot discover with `Get-Command`, and only barely with `Get-Help` (you'll get a lot of results, most of which aren't relevant).

Instead, consult the conceptual [about_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators) help topic for help on operators.

This gap in discoverability between *commands* and *operators* is unfortunate - [GitHub issue #11339](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11339) suggests extending `Get-Help` to support lookup by operator symbols too.
In the meantime, the [`Show-OperatorHelp`](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/146f3202a810a74cb54a2d353ee4003f) custom function can provide this functionality (an MIT-licensed Gist; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59324892/45375) for a discussion).

---

**Overview of symbol-relevant help topics and information**:

- [about_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators) documents *all* operators.
- [about_Script_Blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) documents script blocks and their literal form, `{ ... }`
- [about_Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays) documents arrays and their quasi-literal form, `@(...)` - though note that `@(...)` is technically an *operator* and is therefore also  covered in `about_Operators`
- [about_Hash_Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) documents hash tables (hashtables) and their literal form, `@{ .. .}`
- [about_Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) discusses argument splatting, i.e. the ability to pass a set of arguments (parameter values) via a variable containing a hashtable or array, which must be referenced via `@` rather than `$` (e.g, `@params`).
- [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules) documents *quoting*, i.e. `'...'` and `"..."` strings and their here-string variants, `@'<newline>...<newline>'@` and `@"<newline>...<newline>"@`
- [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) documents PowerShell's *escape sequences*, whose syntax is based on PowerShell's *escape character*, `` ` ``, the so-called *backtick*
- [about_Comment_Based_Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comment_Based_Help) - indirectly - documents PowerShell's *comment syntax*, `#` for to-the-end-of-the-line comments, and `<# ... #>` for block comments (which can be used both in-line and may span multiple lines).
- A symbol not covered by the topics above is `;` the *statement separator* (which is only needed if you place *multiple* statements on a given line).
- To discover all *commands* that start with a symbol (non-word character), use the following:

  ```
  Get-Command -Type All | Where Name -Match '^\W'
  ```